# Refresh id_token ADAL: Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, adal.js

I'm using Angular 4 with ADAL to authenticate users in my web application, using ng2-adal library which is a wrapper for adal.js.

The problem I'm facing is the following:
So the token expires after a time limit and I have a canActivate route guard that checks if the user is authenticated. If not, it navigates the users to the login page. This is how my route guard is looking:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { AdalService } from 'ng2-adal/dist/core';

@Injectable()
export class RouteGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router, private adalService: AdalService) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (this.adalService.userInfo.isAuthenticated) {
      return true;
    } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/user-login']);
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

so whenever the token expires, the user is navigated to the login page, which is annoying for the users. Is there a way to renew the token whenever it expires?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. This is how I added it:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { AdalService } from 'ng2-adal/dist/core';

@Injectable()
export class RouteGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router, private adalService: AdalService) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    if (this.adalService.userInfo.isAuthenticated) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.adalService.acquireToken(this.adalService.config.clientId).toPromise().then((data) => {
      console.log('Generating a new authentication token.');
      return true;
    },
     (error) => {
       console.log('No user logged in.');
       this.router.navigate(['/user-login']);
       return false;
     }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and my fix worked.
In app.component.ts, add this code to ngOnit().

```
this.adalService.handleWindowCallback();
 this.adalService.acquireToken(this.adalService.config.loginResource).subscribe(token => {
  this.adalService.userInfo.token = token;
  if (this.adalService.userInfo.authenticated === false) {
    this.adalService.userInfo.authenticated = true;
    this.adalService.userInfo.error = '';
  }
}, error => {
  this.adalService.userInfo.authenticated = false;
  this.adalService.userInfo.error = error;
  this.adalService.login();
});
```

When token expires, app component gets called, and acquire token refreshes the token silently. But the `this.adalService.userInfo.authenticated` is still false leading to redirection or again calling login method. So manually setting it to true fixes the redirection error. `this.adalService.config.loginResource` this is automactically set by adal-angular itself with the resource that we need token for.

Also add       `expireOffsetSeconds: 320,` to adal configuration data settings along with

```
tenant: configData.adalConfig.tenant,
  clientId: configData.adalConfig.clientId,
  redirectUri: window.location.origin,
```

expireoffsetseconds invalidates the token based on the time that we specify before its actual expiry.